# ASCII compressor works for short test file, not on long

Tags: c, compression, bit-manipulation

The current project in Systems Programming is to come up with an ASCII compressor that removes the top zero bit and writes the contents to the file.

In order to facilitate decompression, the original file size is written to file, then the compressed char bytes.  There are two files to run tests on- one that is 63 bytes long, and the other is 5344213 bytes.  My code below works as expected for the first test file, as it writes 56 bytes of compressed text plus 4 bytes of file header.

However, when I try it on the long test file, the compressed version is 3 bytes shorter than the original, when it should be roughly 749KiB smaller, or 14% of original size.  I've worked out the binary bit shift values for the first two write loops of the long test file, and they match up what is being recorded on my test printout.

```
while ( (characters= read(openReadFile, unpacked, BUFFER)) >0 ){
   unsigned char packed[7]; //compression storage
   int i, j, k, writeCount, endLength, endLoop;

    //loop through the buffer array
    for (i=0; i< characters-1; i++){
        j= i%7; 

        //fill up the compressed array
        packed[j]= packer(unpacked[i], unpacked[i+1], j);

        if (j == 6){
            writeCalls++; //track how many calls made

            writeCount= write(openWriteFile, packed, sizeof (packed));
            int packedSize= writeCount;
            for (k=0; k<7 && writeCalls < 10; k++)
                printf("%X ", (int)packed[k]);      

            totalWrittenBytes+= packedSize;
            printf(" %d\n", packedSize);
            memset(&packed[0], 0, sizeof(packed)); //clear array

            if (writeCount < 0)
                printOpenErrors(writeCount);
        }
        //end of buffer array loop
        endLength= characters-i;
        if (endLength < 7){

            for (endLoop=0; endLoop < endLength-1; endLoop++){
                packed[endLoop]= packer(unpacked[endLoop], unpacked[endLoop+1], endLoop);
            }

            packed[endLength]= calcEndBits(endLength, unpacked[endLength]);
        }
    } //end buffer array loop
} //end file read loop
```

The packer function:

```
//calculates the compressed byte value for the array
char packer(char i, char j, int k){
    char packStyle;

    switch(k){
        //shift bits based on mod value with 8
        case 0:
                packStyle= ((i & 0x7F) << 1) | ((j & 0x40) >> 6);
            break;
        case 1:
            packStyle= ((i & 0x3F) << 2) | ((j & 0x60) >> 5);
            break;
        case 2:
            packStyle= ((i & 0x1F) << 3) | ((j & 0x70) >> 4);
            break;
        case 3:
            packStyle= ((i & 0x0F) << 4) | ((j & 0x78) >> 3);
            break;
        case 4:
            packStyle= ((i & 0x07) << 5) | ((j & 0x7C) >> 2);
            break;
        case 5:
            packStyle= ((i & 0x03) << 6) | ((j & 0x7E) >> 1);
            break;
        case 6:
            packStyle= ( (i & 0x01 << 7) | (j & 0x7F));
            break;
    }

    return packStyle;
}
```

I've verified that there are 7 bytes written out every time the packed buffer is flushed, and there are 763458 write calls made for the long file, which match up to 5344206 bytes written.

I'm getting the same hex codes from the printout that I worked out in binary beforehand, and I can see the top bit of every byte removed. So why aren't the bit shifts being reflected in the results?

Comment: @Andrew sounds like it, but let Jason tag it if so, just to be sure. It's a well put question regardless

Comment: @Andrew & Earlz, it is homework, however the current attitude here at SO is the homework tag shouldn't be used, so thats why I refrained from it.  Also, in the first paragraph, I stated this was a project for Systems Programming

Comment: ah I haven't been up to date enough at Meta to know the current preferences of the community :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, since this is homework I'll just give you a few hints without giving out a solution.

First are you sure that the 56 bytes you get on the first file are the right bytes? Sure the count looks good, but you got lucky on count (proof is the second test file). I can immediately see at least two key mistakes in the code.

To make sure you have the right output, the byte count is not enough. You need to dig deeper. How about checking the bytes themselves one by one. 63 characters is not that much to go heh? There are many ways you can do this. You could use `od` (a pretty good Linux/Unix tool to look at the binary contents of files, if you're on Windows use some Hex editor). Or you could print out debug information from within your program.

Good luck.

Comment: ok, are the mistakes in the stat gathering code, or in the shifting?  Also, I ran the code through ddd, and the packed array contents matched up with what I worked out on paper following the packer function logic for the first 20 elements.

Comment: Ha, but did the paper logic check that the code worked the way you expect the code to work? Or did the paper logic check that the code matched with the actual requirement? The packer function logic is fine, it's how you use the packer function logic that breaks.

Comment: What do you mean by that?  The values sent to the function are based on the loop counter, which avoids array overflow.  Also, the paper logic was independent verification that the shifting was working right, so the bug must be with the switch variable.  Am I on the right track?

Comment: Like I said, check the output byte by byte on your small test file and you will have the answer. It should jump in your eyes. And remember there are two key mistakes.

Comment: I found one of them.  the packer function works from 0-7, but I'm also including buffer[7] when the loop resets itself, when it is already represented in packed[6].  Any hints on the other?

Comment: @Jason: Great, that was the first one to find. Did you fix it? Now count the bytes again. The other one should become obvious when you check the end of the test file and the end of your output.

Comment: It got fixed, the problem was the first slot of the packed array was not being filled after the first loop.

Comment: @Jason: Oh, I had not seen that one. There must be another one then. Did you check all the bytes to the end? Hmm. I just got why you did not see the second problem I was referring to. You must try a small test file that is not a multiple of 7 bytes, then you'll see what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you expect the output to be 14% shorter than the input? How could it, when you store a byte into packed as many times as there are input bytes, except for the last group? The size of the output will always be within 7 of the size of the input.

Comment: the original file size is 5344213 bytes, and the compressed version is 4676193 bytes, which is 12.5% shorter than the input.  One byte is 12.5% of a bit.

Comment: @Jason You said the compressed version is 3 bytes shorter than the original, and that you expect it to be 14% shorter. Now you say it's 4676193 bytes, and should be 12.5% Shorter. Make up your mind.

Comment: @Jason "but I'm also including buffer[7] when the loop resets itself, when it is already represented in packed[6]" -- which was my point; your loop was outputing as many bytes as it read.