# (C) how to fix this algorithm for z827 ASCII compression?

Tags: c, algorithm, compression, bit-manipulation

noob warning.

I'm trying to create a compression program. It takes a .txt with ASCII characters as an argument, and cuts off the leading 0 of the binary representation of each character.

It does this by using the last 2 bytes of two different integers. A character with a leading zero is put into the 4th byte of the integer 'write', and the next character is put into the 3rd byte of the integer 'temp'. The 'temp' int is then shifted to the right once, and then OR'd with 'write', so that the leading zero slot has been filled with data we need. This repeats, with the shift counter increasing after every character. The first case is a bit odd. The algorithm isn't very complex if written out on paper.

I feel like I've tried everything. I've been over the algorithm so many times. I'm pretty sure the problem is when shift_counter gets to 8.. but it should work fine. It just doesn't. I can show you why here (the code is further down):

This is the hex dump of my output:

```
0000000    3f  00  00  00  41  10  68  9e  6e  c3  d9  65  10  88  5e  c6
0000020    d3  41  e6  74  9a  5d  06  d1  df  a0  7a  7d  5e  06  a5  dd
0000040    20  3a  bd  3c  a7  a7  dd  67  10  e8  5d  a7  83  e8  e8  72
0000060    19  a4  c7  c9  6e  a0  f1  f8  dd  86  cb  cb  f3  f9  3c    
0000077
```

And the correct output:

```
0000000    3f  00  00  00  41  d0  3c  dd  86  b3  cb  20  7a  19  4f  07
0000020    99  d3  ec  32  88  fe  06  d5  e7  65  50  da  0d  a2  97  e7
0000040    f4  b4  fb  0c  7a  d7  e9  20  3a  ba  0c  d2  e3  64  37  d0
0000060    f8  dd  86  cb  cb  f3  79  fa  ed  76  29  00  0a  0a        
0000076
```

code:

```
int compress(char *filename_ptr){

    int in_fd;
    in_fd = open(filename_ptr, O_RDONLY);

    //set pointer to the end of the file, find file size, then reset position 
    //by closing/opening
    unsigned int file_bytes = lseek(in_fd, 0, SEEK_END);
    close(in_fd);
    in_fd = open(filename_ptr, O_RDONLY);

    //store file contents in buffer
    unsigned char read_buffer[file_bytes];
    read(in_fd, read_buffer, file_bytes);

    //file where the output will be stored
    int out_fd;
    creat("output.txt", 0644);
    out_fd = open("output.txt", O_WRONLY);

    //sets file size in header (needed for decompression, this is the size of the
    //file before compression. everything after this we write this 4-byte int
    //is a 1 byte char
    write(out_fd, &file_bytes, 4);

    unsigned int writer;
    unsigned int temp;
    unsigned char out_char;

    int i;
    int shift_count = 8;
    for(i = 0; i < file_bytes; i++){


      if(shift_count == 8){
          writer = read_buffer[i];
          temp = temp & 0x00000000;
          temp = read_buffer[i+1] << 8;
          shift_count = 1;
      }else{

        //moves the next char's bits to the left, for the purpose of filling the
        //8 bit buffer (writer) via OR operation
        temp = read_buffer[i] << 8;
      }
      temp = temp >> shift_count;
      writer = writer | temp;

      //output right byte of writer
      unsigned int right_byte = writer & 0x000000ff;

      //output right_byte as a char
      out_char = (char) right_byte;

      //write_buffer[i] = out_char;
      write(out_fd, &out_char, 1);

      //clear right side of writer
      writer = writer & 0x0000ff00;

      //shift left side of writer to the right by 8
      writer = writer >> 8;        

      shift_count++;

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: see that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15075557/masking-most-significant-bit

Comment: That will give you at most 1 / 8 (i.e., 12.5%) savings, and only for text.

Comment: `temp = temp & 0x00000000;` looks like a premature optimisation for `temp = 0;`. Why don't you let your compiler perform these micro-optimisations for you? Don't you think it's smart enough, if it can perform far more complex optimisations such as dead code elimination? `temp = read_buffer[i] << 8;` looks like undefined behaviour. See Alexandre's link for more details on that.

Comment: Suppose `out_char = (char) right_byte;` were to raise an implementation defined computational signal indicating that `char` isn't able to represent the value of `right_byte`... Suppose the implementation defined default signal handler were to ignore the signal. According to section 7.14.1.1, point 2 of the C standard this sequence of implementation defined behaviours would land you in undefined behaviour territory.

Comment: The http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5201571/ascii-compressor-works-for-short-test-file-not-on-long discusses the same "z827 ASCII compression" system.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that input and output are too strongly coupled.

At some point, the program *should* be reading (roughly) the 80th octet from the input and writing (roughly) the 70th octet to the output, because you want to (on average) write 7 bits out for every 8 bits you read in, right?

What the loop

```
for(i = 0; i < file_bytes; i++){
    ...
    ... = read_buffer[i];
    ...
    write(out_fd, &out_char, 1);
    ...
}
```

actually seems to be doing is:
On the 70th pass through the loop -- when 70==i --
it's reading the 70th octet from the input and writing the 70th octet to the output.
On the 80th pass through the loop -- when 80==i --
it's reading the 80th octet from the input and writing the 80th octet to the output.

You must decide:
Do you want "i" to represent the number of *input* characters processed, or the number of *output* chars processed?
Because it's not possible to do both -- it's not possible to have 70 equal 80.

Perhaps something like this is closer to what you wanted:

```
/* test.c
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15080239/c-how-to-fix-this-algorithm-for-z827-ascii-compression
WARNING: untested code.
*/

int compress(char *filename_ptr){

    int in_fd;
    in_fd = open(filename_ptr, O_RDONLY);

    //set pointer to the end of the file, find file size, then reset position 
    //by closing/opening
    unsigned int file_bytes = lseek(in_fd, 0, SEEK_END);
    close(in_fd);
    in_fd = open(filename_ptr, O_RDONLY);

    //store file contents in buffer
    unsigned char read_buffer[file_bytes];
    read(in_fd, read_buffer, file_bytes);

    //file where the output will be stored
    int out_fd;
    creat("output.txt", 0644);
    out_fd = open("output.txt", O_WRONLY);

    //sets file size in header (needed for decompression, this is the size of the
    //file before compression. everything after this we write this 4-byte int
    //is a 1 byte char
    write(out_fd, &file_bytes, 4);

    unsigned int writer;
    unsigned int temp;
    unsigned char out_char;

    int i;
    int writer_bits = 0; // 0 bits of data in writer so far
    for(i = 0; i < file_bytes; i++){
      // i is the number of (7 bit ASCII) characters
      // read from the input so far.

      // add 7 more bits to the writer
      temp = read_buffer[i];
      //moves the next char's bits to the left, for the purpose of filling the
      //8 bit buffer (writer) via OR operation
      //(avoid overwriting the "writer_bits" of good bits
      //already in the buffer).
      temp = read_buffer[i] << writer_bits;
      writer = writer | temp;
      writer_bits = writer_bits + 7;

      //output right byte of writer
      unsigned int right_byte = writer & 0x000000ff;

      //output right_byte as a char
      out_char = (unsigned char) right_byte;

      // output 8 bits of data whenever
      // we have *at least* 8 bits of data in the writer buffer.
      if(writer_bits >= 8){

          //write_buffer[i] = out_char;
          write(out_fd, &out_char, 1);

          //shift left side of writer to the right by 8
          writer = writer >> 8;

          writer_bits = writer_bits - 8;
      }else{
          // 7 or fewer bits in writer --
      // skip writing until next time.
      }
    }

    // is there any leftover bits still in writer?
    if(writer_bits > 0){
          //write_buffer[i] = out_char;
          write(out_fd, &out_char, 1);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

(Currently the program reads the entire input file into RAM, then writes the entire output file. Some programmers prefer to read a little at a time, then write a little at a time. Both approaches have advantages and disadvantages).